# Can someone please explain "How we can prioritize the load to jboss instances?"

Tags: jboss5.x

I just want to understand is there any kind of worker manager concept like weblogic server in Jboss? if yes please explain me how can we achieve?

Thanks,
Amarnath

Answer (score 0):

You can by setting following properties in file conf/workers.properties

```
# Load-balancing behaviour
worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=node1,node2
worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=1
```

Read more [Configuring load balancing using Apache and mod_jk](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Administration_And_Configuration_Guide/clustering-http.html)

Hoping this helps.

Cheers !!

Comment: Hello Sachin,  Thanks for your valuable answer..from load balancing point of you we distribute the load to nodes..my question is there possible we can control the work load from jboss server itself?